# Why Python code modified in Docker container is not updated

Tags: docker

I have looked at some other answers but none seem to be quite what I'm looking for.

I am coding in Python within a virtual environment created with Docker containers. However, I often encounter the following error when running the code.

```
cv2.rectangle(vis, (int(bbox[0]), int(bbox[1])), (int(bbox[2]), int(bbox[3])), (255, 255, 0), 1)


NameError: name 'img' is not defined
```

There is no variable called `'img'` in the code where the error occurred. So, if you print an appropriate sentence using `print('sdjlksfljkw')`, etc., the error disappears.

I want to know why this phenomenon occurs and if there is a solution.

Comment: Can you please add all the code from the file